# Python export to .csv without overwriting columns in for loop

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, csv, for-loop, csvwriter

I am trying to write data from several documents (implemented in a a for loop) to a csv file in Python 3. However, the column gets overwritten every time. How can I make that data from the individual documents be printed on a csv in the rows below, without overwriting?

```
from pdfminer.high_level import extract_text
for selectedfile in glob.glob(r'C:\Users\...\*.pdf'):
    text = extract_text(selectedfile)

Y = set(text)
Z = []
Znew = []
for val in Y:
    occurrences = wordlist2.count(val)
    if occurrences > 50:  # define min. no. of occurrences
        # print(val, ':', occurrences)
        Z.append(val)
        Znew.append(occurrences)

dict = {'Stem': Z, 'Count': Znew}
df = pd.DataFrame(dict)
df.to_csv('Exported list.csv', header=True, index=True, encoding='utf-8')
```

Comment: What do you mean by "the column gets overwritten"? What is the current outcome, what is the expected outcome?

Comment: I think he wants to append new data to old data without overwriting it

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in that first `for` loop. You keep replacing `text` with new extracted text and only process the final extraction. You could move the processing into the `for` loop to work on each extraction. In this example, I've opened the file beforehand and written the header once. Then its a question of making sure the index is correct for each write.

```
from pdfminer.high_level import extract_text
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

with open('Exported list.csv', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as outfile:
    outfile.write(",Stem,Count\n") # header
    base = 0
    for selectedfile in glob.glob(r'C:\Users\...\*.pdf'):
        text = extract_text(selectedfile)

        Y = set(text)
        Z = []
        Znew = []
        for val in Y:
            occurrences = wordlist2.count(val)
            if occurrences > 50:  # define min. no. of occurrences
                # print(val, ':', occurrences)
                Z.append(val)
                Znew.append(occurrences)

        dict = {'Stem': Z, 'Count': Znew}
        df = pd.DataFrame(dict, index=np.arange(base, base+len(Z)))
        df.to_csv(outfile, index=True)
        base += len(Z)
```